# package bundler 1.0.13 gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have a production environment with no access out to web servers and no compiler, both by policy.

I have installed bundler 0.9.26 by going to a development server with web access, putting the bundler version in my Gemfile, doing a bundle package, copying bundler-0.9.26.gem to the production server, and running gem install bundler-0.9.26.gem.

However, now I need to install bundler 1.0.13, and when I do those steps, bundle package does not create a bundler gem file.

So, how do I install bundler 1.0.13 on my production server?

BTW, I am trying to get past the uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError) error.  So advice in doing that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me the answer.  Gem fetch the bundler .gem file.